# Why doesn't the king of Belah get a name?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, names, malchut-royalty, parashat-lech-lecha, cities

[Bereishis 14:2](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8209#v=2) names the 5 kings who were on Team B in the war between the 4 kings and the 5 kings.  Regarding 4 of the 5 kings on Team B, we are told their name and their domain.  But by the king of Belah, we only get the name of his locale.

How come he doesn't get named?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Ramban says the reason why his name is not mentioned is due to the fact that the city was small with few people living there, he was not famous.

The Shaarei Aharon (from whom I am quoting all these answers) suggests that the names mentioned here are based on the evil nature of the people we are mentioning. Being that the king of Tzoar was not so evil yet, and the sins of the city were not so great, his name is not mentioned.

Thirdly, he brings the sefer Chomas Anach who writes that the name of the king was Bella as well, and we find this idea in the Sefer HaYashar, and Bella the king of Tzoar.